# How to use V2Form in Bouncy Castle, Java?

Tags: java, security, certificate, bouncycastle

I'm developing a Profile Certificate software, and the use of V2Form for a BasicCertificateID is needed.

```
                    issuerGenName = new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(new X500Name(issuerName)));
        ASN1Integer issuerSerialNumber = new ASN1Integer(Integer.parseInt(mainWindow.getIssuerSerialNumber()));
        //IssuerSerial baseCertificateID = new IssuerSerial(issuerGenName,  issuerSerialNumber);
        ASN1EncodableVector vec = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        ASN1EncodableVector vecS = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        vecS.add(issuerGenName);
        vecS.add(issuerSerialNumber);
        ASN1Sequence seq = new DERSequence(vecS);
        IssuerSerial baseCertificateID  = IssuerSerial.getInstance(seq);
        ASN1TaggedObject tagged = new DERTaggedObject(0, baseCertificateID);
        //TODO Refazer
        vec.add(issuerGenName);
        vec.add(tagged);
        ASN1Sequence seq2 = new DERSequence(vec);

        V2Form teste = new V2Form(seq2);


        issuer = new AttCertIssuer(teste); 
        attIssuer = new AttributeCertificateIssuer(issuer);
```

But this won't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ASN1TaggedObject tagged = new DERTaggedObject(0, baseCertificateID);

Should read

ASN1TaggedObject tagged = new DERTaggedObject(false, 0, baseCertificateID);

The object is meant to be implicitly, not explicitly tagged.

One other thing, in BC you should always use the pattern V2Form.getInstance() rather than calling a constructor that takes a sequence. We're slowly stamping these out, the main problem is it's not really safe, in some situations you can get class cast exceptions unexpectedly as the sequence constructor can't handle all the situations getInstance() can.

For BC's part, V2Form really needs a couple more constructors, these should appear in the next beta (149b09) out in the next couple of days.

Regards,

David